# Sort data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I a have problem - I am showing in my html `data` from javascript, and i have to sort it after click. Here is my code:

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "ASD",
    "src": "https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "FGH",
    "src": "https://cloudfour.com/examples/img-currentsrc/images/kitten-small.png"
  }
]
const info_container = document.querySelector('.info-container')

const sort = () => {
  data.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id))

  fetchData()
}

const fetchData = () => {
  data.forEach((item, index) => {
  const img = document.createElement("img");
  const title = document.createElement('h3')

  const node = document.createTextNode(item.src);
  const node_title = document.createTextNode(item.title)

  title.appendChild(node_title)
  img.src = item.src

  info_container.appendChild(title)
  info_container.appendChild(img);

})
}
window.onload = function() {
  fetchData()
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><button onclick="sort()">sort</button></div>
  <div class="info-container">    
</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yjn4jaLN45pYJHFZBZLn?p=preview

Instead of updating my actual view, a new one is created, how to fix that?

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: you're not calling `sort` anywhere ... so, that's a thing

Comment: Look in plunker, i am calling sort onclick button in html

Comment: why should I look elsewhere? If you do call sort, then of course it adds to the data ... all you do is appendChild

Comment: i have already edit my question

Comment: remove the old content and then add the sorted content

Comment: I can't see all of your code but I suspect it's something to do with calling .appendchild() instead you should be using innerHtml = "" before appending more children or use some other DOM Api

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the contents of `info_container` each time `fetchData` is called:

```
const fetchData = () => {
  info_container.innerHTML = "";
  //Rest of the code
}
```

[Modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aHWngJ64vmd7XCITVtEp?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

1. It is strange you don't release your `info_container` children number increases on each click event. You want to replace your `info_container` content with a new one, so your new content structure doesn't matter at first glance , you should write a function that does the job, checking that you could at least replace a string with an new one. With @jack Bashford reply you have a solution
2. Second wording could help in a code, just minor remark thought, your fetchData is not fetching anything at all